# Hadoop sorting by value in a Reduce Side Join

Tags: sorting, hadoop

So I'm just working on some Hadoop training getting to learn the lay of the land, and I'm attempting to do a reduce side join, which I have functioning, except for the secondary sort.

So the basics:

Two files
One has player,team,salary
Another has player,team,home runs

Output should be team,player,salary,home runs

The New York Mets should be partitioned into one file, while all the other crappy teams should be put into another.

Each of these files should be sorted by team, and secondarily by player salary.

I'm using a key of team,playerID to join on and that works, but I have no idea how I would sort by salary since only one of the two files has it.

Is this a possible task or can this only be accomplished via a map side join?

Answer (score 0):

For this "The New York Mets should be partitioned into one file, while all the other crappy teams should be put into another."

You can use custom partitioner and return 0 for New York Mets and 1 for others.

Regarding sorting on salary, you are right - it is efficient to do using map side join. If data set is not very big, you can sort in the reducer by looping twice on the reducer input. In first you have to build some in memory collection to store the sorted data and in the second loop you can emit the data. But it is highly inefficient on larger data set - especially if each of the team have too many players, it will be slow as well as it can run into out of memory issues.